# How to sum over a computed variable in django?

Tags: django, django-models

I have trouble find the solution to the following simple problem. The following command

```
tenta_data = Konstruktion.objects.all().annotate(tid=Sum(F('antal')))
```

works fine if antal is a variable in the database:

```
class Konstruktion(models.Model):
    antal = models.FloatField()
    .... 
    def anumber(self):
       return .....
```

but how do I do if I want to sum over anumber? Which is a function.

Comment: Shouldn't this be an `aggregate(..)` instead of an `.annotate(..)`. But to answer your question, you have to do this manually, at Python level.

Answer (score 0):

Well the database has no *knowledge* about functions, properties, etc. So that means it can not *automate* this task for you.

The only way you can do this is to calculate it at the *Python* level, like for example:

```
total_anumbers = sum(
    k.anumber()
    for k in Konstruktion.objects.all()
)
```

This will `sum(..)` up the values by *iterating* over the `Konstruktion` objects, and each time calculating the `k.anumber()` and sum these up.

Note that the Python sum works slightly different than the Python equivalent. It will for example *not* ignore the `NULL`/`None` values. Furthermore it can add different type of objects together (like `bool`s with `int`s, etc., given such addition is implemented).

Other more advanced aggregates are usually even harder to *mimic* at the Python level.

Comment: Thanks, I feared so. But now it is clarified